# Include HTML page into another HTML div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, include

Ok - this is driving me bonkers. Such a simple load but nothing is happening. Any ideas how I can resolves this? Ideally I would like to create components ( header / footer / etc) to reuse across all.

Here is the HTML I am using for a test.

```
<html>

<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#included-page").load("test.html");
   });
 </script>

</head>

<body>
 <div id="included-page"></div>
 <!-- insert page 2 test -->
 <h1>This Page 1</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the test page I am trying to load

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Included from page test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the network tab of dev tools to see why the AJAX request fails. Most likely a path error. ***However*** including content on the client side isn't a great idea. Do it server side instead. Also, the included HTML shouldn't have its own `doctype`, `head` etc, just the content to be injected

Answer (score 0):

I would find using an `include` statement easier, because no javascript is needed:

```html
<html>

<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#included-page").load("test.html");
   });
 </script>

</head>

<body>

 <!--#include virtual="test.html"-->

 <h1>This Page 1</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: that is not a comment, but include statements have the same format as HTML comments.

Comment: I have tried the "include" statement as well with no luck. I also remove the HTML (doctype,..etc) and both files are in the same local directory. I also tried is various browsers.

Comment: That's strange. Do you get an error message in your browser, for example that the page was not found? You could also try using the full URL to `test.html` instead of the relative one. If that doesn't work, i guess you'll have to find some other solution – good luck!

Comment: I am not getting an error just not loading in the "test.html" even now on a server with a full URL link. It can be viewed here: http://wh481912.ispot.cc